# Python Package Installation (Trigger) on Windows

Tags: python

I am having a really tough time getting a python package (Trigger - http://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to work on Windows.

I am now at the point where the package itself is installed and I believe so are the dependencies.  The last part of configuring the package asks to copy some files into the /etc/trigger directory (Linux), and I do not know what the Windows equivalent path for this would be.

Does anyone know where to put package files that typically would reside in /etc/package_name on a Linux system?

The error I am receiving is below.  I am not sure if this is exactly the problem, but I am very confused as this is my first time running Python on windows:

```
>> from trigger.netdevices import NetDevices
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trigger\netdevices\__init__.py", line 37, in <
module>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trigger\conf\__init__.py", line 25, in <module
>
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\trigger\conf\global_settings.py", line 25, in
<module>
  File "c:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py", line 96, in join
    assert len(path) > 0
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

Comment: Is this different from C:\PythonXX\Lib\site-packages?

Comment: Run it and see where it is looking when it fails?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create configuration directory
Trigger expects to find its configuration files to be in /etc/trigger.

**This can be customized using the PREFIX configuration variable within settings.py:**

sudo mkdir /etc/trigger

That’s it! Now you’re ready to configure Trigger.

From the documentation just change the directory in settings.py to wherever you would like

**settings.py**

```
# This is where Trigger should look for its files.
PREFIX = '/etc/trigger'
```

make a folder (i.e. "C:\trigger") and change PREFIX to that location.

Comment: The only settings.py is the one that the configuration asks to be placed in /etc/trigger/

Comment: try global_settings.py